# Issue with core dropbox API Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am sync the dropbox api for the first time. i am using the core api directly as i want to download and upload my files from my application to dropbox. I have change the app-key to my app key and app-secret to my app secret, i have included the files in lib folder of my application but i am getting this error

```
Invalid User
```

This is my code is in maindrobbox activity

```
public class Dropbox extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Dropbox";



    // You don't need to change these, leave them alone.
    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";


    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;

    private boolean mLoggedIn;

    // Android widgets
    private Button mSubmit;
    private LinearLayout mDisplay;
    private Button mPhoto;
    private Button mRoulette;

    private ImageView mImage;

    private final String PHOTO_DIR = "/Photos/";

    final static private int NEW_PICTURE = 1;
    private String mCameraFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCameraFileName = savedInstanceState.getString("mCameraFileName");
        }

        // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        // Basic Android widgets
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dropbox);

        checkAppKeySetup();

        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This logs you out if you're logged in, or vice versa
                if (mLoggedIn) {
                    logOut();
                } else {
                    // Start the remote authentication
                    mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(Dropbox.this);
                }
            }
        });

        mDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logged_in_display);

        // This is where a photo is displayed
        mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        // This is the button to take a photo
        mPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_button);

        mPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Picture from camera
                intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // This is not the right way to do this, but for some reason, having
                // it store it in
                // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI isn't working right.

                Date date = new Date();
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");

                String newPicFile = df.format(date) + ".jpg";
                String outPath = "/sdcard/" + newPicFile;
                File outFile = new File(outPath);

                mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
                Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
                Log.i(TAG, "Importing New Picture: " + mCameraFileName);
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    showToast("There doesn't seem to be a camera.");
                }
            }
        });


        // This is the button to take a photo
        mRoulette = (Button)findViewById(R.id.roulette_button);

        mRoulette.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DownloadRandomPicture download = new DownloadRandomPicture(Dropbox.this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, mImage);
                download.execute();
            }
        });

        // Display the proper UI state if logged in or not
        setLoggedIn(mApi.getSession().isLinked());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("mCameraFileName", mCameraFileName);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

        // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
        // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
        // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                session.finishAuthentication();

                // Store it locally in our app for later use
                TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
                storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }

    // This is what gets called on finishing a media piece to import
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == NEW_PICTURE) {
            // return from file upload
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                }
                if (uri == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
                }
                File file = new File(mCameraFileName);

                if (uri != null) {
                    UploadPicture upload = new UploadPicture(this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, file);
                    upload.execute();
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from mediaImport: "
                        + resultCode);
            }
        }
    }

    private void logOut() {
        // Remove credentials from the session
        mApi.getSession().unlink();

        // Clear our stored keys
        clearKeys();
        // Change UI state to display logged out version
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience function to change UI state based on being logged in
     */
    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
            mSubmit.setText("Unlink from Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mSubmit.setText("Link with Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    private void checkAppKeySetup() {
        // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
        if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") ||
                APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
            showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the Dropbox ap before trying it.");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Check if the app has set up its manifest properly.
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String scheme = "db-" + APP_KEY;
        String uri = scheme + "://" + AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/test";
        testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (0 == pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0).size()) {
            showToast("URL scheme in your app's " +
                    "manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a " +
                    "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the " +
                    "scheme: " + scheme);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
     * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
     * time (which is not to be done, ever).
     *
     * @return Array of [access_key, access_secret], or null if none stored
     */
    private String[] getKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
        String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
        if (key != null && secret != null) {
            String[] ret = new String[2];
            ret[0] = key;
            ret[1] = secret;
            return ret;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
     * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
     * time (which is not to be done, ever).
     */
    private void storeKeys(String key, String secret) {
        // Save the access key for later
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, key);
        edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, secret);
        edit.commit();
    }

    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }

    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session;

        String[] stored = getKeys();
        if (stored != null) {
            AccessTokenPair accessToken = new AccessTokenPair(stored[0], stored[1]);
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE, accessToken);
        } else {
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE);
        }

        return session;
    }
```

Comment: It would really help if you said where that error comes from (something you see on the device, or part of an exception) and when it happens. If it's an exception, please share the full stack trace and show us which line of code triggers the exception. If it's an error on the device, tell us what happens before the error is displayed.

Comment: its not an error actually, when the dropbox activity runs it simply  opens a webpage with displaying Invalid User. i tried to find out the exception invalid user, but its not there

Comment: My guess would be that this app is in development and hasn't been enabled for more users, and you're trying to log in via a different account (not the account that created the app). Any chance that's true? You can enable more users in the app console (dropbox.com/developers/apps).